# Better understand on format keyword in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I usually send mail in rails using following code:

```
mail(:to => 'myname@gmail.com', :subject => 'testing') do |format|
      format.html { render layout: true }
end.deliver
```

Could any one explain to me what format keyword is doing here? It's a method name, object name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `format` is an object supplied to the block being executed and the object has convenience methods like `html` that take a block argument.

It's not a *keyword*, it's just a local variable declared in the block definition.

If you want to know more about what it is:

```
raise format.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

The mail method has the option of providing a block where you can specify which templates to explicitly render. "format" in this case is a local variable in the block function.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html